# Ember v. 2.x: watch vendor folder

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm developing an Ember-JS application with a lot of JavaScript that performs of all kind of UX and styling tasks.

Because these tasks fall out of the scope the MVC-logic, I've put them into modules that I put in the vendor map.

Putting them into the Vendor folder doesn't mean I'm done tweaking these files, but to test them, I'm required to re-start the ember-server over and over again.

***How can I make Ember watch these JS-files in my vendor folder and re-compile them when I change them?***

The following page answers for Ember v. 1, but doesn't apply to Ember 2.0: https://discuss.emberjs.com/t/solved-watch-addon-directory-for-changes/6410/4

I also tried creating an addon, but ember (cli) answers with: “You cannot use the addon command inside an ember-cli project.”

Comment: My recommendation is that you don't put them into the `vendor` folder. If you write the code, putt it into the `app` folder. You could just create a `custom` folder, or use the `utils` folder. This will also give you the benefit of babel transformation. `vendor` is usually for external code that you can't get by `npm` or `bower`.

Comment: Thanks. That doesn't wok either. I get a Build Error straight away. I'm maybe confused because of the different Ember versions. The following link seems to say it can't be done. https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/4717

Comment: @Lux Would you post your comment as the answer? Then I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a while to connect all the pieces of information scattered over internet, but using @Lux 's anwers, this is what I found out.

1) Using the ember-cli, I generate a 'utility' (hence the utils folder):

```
ember g util grid-layout
```

This gives you a JS-file  *“app/utils/grid-layout.js”* template to fill in. In my case, it was a matter of…

2) copy-paste the body of the function I created earlier, into the body of the function that ember-cli came up with:

```
export default function gridLayout(tree) {
… 
return tree
}
```

3) Importing the function in the controller, in my case controllers/index.js. I found different examples on how to do this, with and without curly braces and using different paths to the module file, but this is what made it work for me:

```
import Ember from "ember";
import  gridLayout  from "../utils/grid-layout";

export default Ember.Controller.extend({…
```

Links:

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

https://blog.abuiles.com/blog/2014/10/03/working-with-javascript-plugins-in-ember-cli/

Answer (score 2):

In ember-cli version 2.11.0 by default its watching vendor foler.
https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/pull/6436